# Extract element from json object array

Tags: java, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have below json response. Below response for layer2 object array there can be x number of items

```
{"data": {
        "layer1": {
            "layer2": [
                {
                    "item1": "result1",
                    "item2": "result2"
                },
                {
                    "item1": "result3",
                    "item2": "result4"
                }
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

My requirement is if I know value of one element (e.g. `item1` value **result4**), How do I get the correspondence item value of `item1` which is **result3**.

I have the below code where I can retrieve the object array. Is that possible to retrieve above with below output.

```
List<Object> actual = response.jsonPath().getList("data.layer1.layer2");
```

Comment: Can you iterate `actual` and filter your required object?

Comment: Why did you use `gridlayer1` when there is only `layer1` object in your JSON? A typo?

Comment: @Fenio Sorry it was a typo. Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant if item2 is result4 then find item1. With the code you have written you can iterate the list and typecast the object to map and check if item2 exists with value result4 then get item1.

```
for(Object item: actual)
{
     if(((Map)item).get("item2").equals("result4")){
        return ((Map)item).get("item1");
     } 
}
```

PS: I haven't tested this code but logically it should work.